# Nested lists and z-index

Tags: html, css

I'm building a navigation menu for a website and the menu has submenus.  When the submenu slides down, it needs to lie behind the main navigation.  I've tried using z-index but it won't work.  Since the submenu is a child of the LI, is it not able to lie behind?

The code is a bit verbose due to the image sprite, so I'll link to a pastie:

http://pastie.org/1100075

And here's some images to support my explanation.

Desired outcome: [http://imgur.com/WeU5T.png](https://imgur.com/WeU5T.png)

Current outcome: [http://imgur.com/0ZC4v.png](https://imgur.com/0ZC4v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Move the `li.home a` link out side of `ul.nav`, and put it inside of an absolutely positioned block element with a `z-index` > 0.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help me while still maintaining the functionality of a submenu.  The submenu needs to be visible when the main LI is hovered, so, to make that work, the submenu still needs to be contained within the main LI, which I think is where the problem lies.

Comment: Are you using Javascript to show/hide the submenu? If so, I don't see why the actual markup is an issue.